# discord.py how would I put if user has admin permissions in a if statement?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

in a perfect world i would like to do this:

```
if user who sent message has admin rights:

    answer()
```

but since this isn't a perfect world I am doing somthing more like this:

```
if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        if (somthng to detect if admin)
            print('hello')
```

i am missing that one line then i would be happy but i can't find anything. When i go on the internett it says to use somthing like this:

```
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(admin=True)  
async def stock(self, ctx, Member: discord.Member):
          print (hello)
```

but sinnce i am too dumb to understand anything that isnt if statements I don't know how to make this compatible with an if statement or how to make the rest of my code compatible with that

can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receive a message in a server, the `message.author` object will be of the `member` class.
The `member` class has an attribue of `member.guild_permissions` [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions).

This returns a `permissions` object. This is an abstract class, which can be found [here in the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions). It has a lot of utility methods and the one you are looking for is `administrator` [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.administrator).

Your if statement should therefore look something like this:

```py
if message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
     print('hello')
```